# How do firefighting helicopters refill their water reservoirs while hovering?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

I have been curious these days about how firefighting helicopters go about refilling their water reservoirs while hovering, and I was wondering,

If the helicopter hovers $5 m$ above the refill stations - the vertical hanging pipe is $5 m$ long. Is it more efficient to have a centrifugal pump at the bottom (at the water inlet) or at the top (basically inside the water tank or somewhere inside the helicopter)?

With my basic understanding of physics creating suction at the top requires a harder working pump.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is no different from filling a tank at height from a tank on ground from the perspective of energy.

If the pump is  fitted in helicopter it would have to carry it around as an extra payload. So ground based pumps are definitely better here.

Helicopters, practically all vehicles, are made to be as light as possible.

Comment: An onboard pump has the advantage that it can get water from any convenient lake or river.

Comment: You are absolutely right but question was about refuelling

Comment: The question was about refilling water tanks.

Comment: Sorry my mistake 

Answer (score 0):

all the firefighting helicopter rigs I have seen where the helicopter suctions up its own water through a pickup tube instead of snagging a filled bucket on a cable use a very powerful pump driven off one of the helicopter's engines. The pump is inside the helicopter and not on the end of the pickup tube. This arrangement will draw water by suction for pickup tubes shorter than 33 feet.